# Virtual memory: memory leak on unfreed malloc?

Tags: memory-leaks

```
int main()
  {
    char * str = (char *) malloc(100);
    return 0;
  }
```

I was told that code above would cause a memory leak. But with the help of virtual memory:

1. Suppose the executable is `a.out`, then `a.out`has its own addressing space and page table.
2. When `a.out` terminates without `free(str)`, memory leak happens in `a.out`'s vitual memory space.
3. However, after termination (or maybe after parent process reaps the terminated process?), data structures about `a.out`'s memory are also destroied.

Does this mean memory leak is totally impossible, as long as the process terminates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard has nothing to say about what happens *after* the program exits.

That's an environmental thing.

However, the vast majority of situations have the `malloc` arena as part of process space which is auto-magically released with the process.

Memory leaks are generally related to memory that you can no longer access (e.g., free) because you've over-written the pointer to it with some other value, and that tends to be a potential problem only while the process exists.

Comment: What if I change the pointer `str` before free the allocated space? Does that cause any harm after the process terminates?

Comment: @wlnirvana, no, for the same reason. It's cleaned up on process exit.

Comment: I got it. So what on earth is `malloc` arena as part of process space ? Does that relate to virtual memory on modern OS?

Comment: Only tangentially. Processes get a chunk of contiguous memory called virtual memory (say locations 0 thru 4G). That's what they use. The OS maps virtual memory addresses to physical memory so that two processes can have the same address (virtual) with different location (physical, including temporarily saved off the hard disk if need be). Processes really only see their virtual memory, including their malloc arena, where their dynamically allocated memory comes from.